# Equivalent norms and inner product

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

It is not hard to give examples of normed spaces which are not inner product spaces. Now let $(V, \|\cdot\|)$ be a normed space.

Is it always possible to construct an inner product on $V$ which gives the same topology on $V$ as before? (As pointed out in comments, in finite dimensional case it it always the case).

Comment: All norms of $\mathbb{R}^n$ are equivalent. And only a few (relatively speaking) are induced by inner products.

Comment: The second question is true for $\mathbb{R}^n$, i.e. all finite-dimensional cases. But is fails for infinite-dimensional ones.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Thanks for the comments. I have edited the question. Do you have a counterexample for the infinite dimensional setting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An inner product space (i.e. the topological vector space induced by an inner product) is reflexive (even: $X$ and $X^\ast$ are isometric), at least if $X$ is complete. And e.g. $\ell_1$ does not have this property.

So at least you need to demand that $X$ and its dual are isometric (in the complete case). And even then there probably are counterexamples.